# How do I get github to syntax highlight Solidity code?

Tags: solidity, syntax-highlighting

I uploaded a smart contract written in Solidity to github but it is not syntax highlighted. Instead it looks like a regular text file. I would like syntax highlighting to be shown on Github. How do I achieve that?

Comment: I think this is a very valid question and relevant to this forum. I think it should be reopened.

Comment: As of January/2020 this is not needed anymore as github recognizes .sol files automatically

Comment: Yup, can confirm that a `.gitattributes` file is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell github that this file is a Solidity file. Github will not recongnize .sol files automatically at the moment. Add this line to your .gitattributes file:

```
*.sol linguist-language=Solidity
```

If you do not have a .gitattributes file you need to create one and place it in the root directory of your git project.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work anymore. Is there a newer method that works?

Comment: @schemar it does work, you may have to wait a while, or push another commit to .sol files for it to take effect.